# Laravel project launches on just localhost

Tags: laravel, localhost, wamp

long time ago, I made a Laravel project and configured the wamp server (on which the project was installed) and the project it self so, that when I type just "localhost" in my browser, it will launch. I don't really remember how I did it, and now I have been struggling for a week or so to remove this, because I can't get trough browser to another project I have recently created. I really don't know what to do... Also if I take the project out of the "www" map on my wamp server, the local host cant be found. Even if type it together with the port number, browser removes the port number from the search box, leaves just the localhost and throws a 404 not found error. I am sure that there is an easy solution to my problem.
Anywho, I hope you can help me, I would really appreciate if You ask more questions, not skip to next problem.
Thanks

ADDITION:
all I'm looking for is a way to run my projects like localhost:80/projectName

Answer (score 0):

The correct way which run the laravel application is the following step:

1. go to your application directory with your cmd in windows or terminal in mac,linux.
2. when you go to you directory just type:

   ```
   php artisan serve
   ```

   and in terminal you see this:

   `Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/`
3. and in last step type in your browser:

   ```
   http://localhost:8000/
   ```

note: every time you run your laravel application just follow these step.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I cant get to my new joomla project trough localhost, because my previous project launches by typing localhost, and by typing localhost/joomla, browser thinks that I want to get to a folder in my old project called joomla.
im sure that its some conf file in wamp server I have to change, but I cant find which one

Comment: I think this is the coookie problem in you browser just you should clear the browsing data from your browser. the answer I post it is about running larravel application according to your title and description.

Comment: Do not think its like that. Tried from different browsers and the result was the same. Just that I have configured my WAMP server so that if I type localhost it jumps straight to my old project